# Why does the shape of a 1D array not show the number of rows as 1?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that numpy array has a method called shape that returns [No.of rows, No.of columns], and shape[0] gives you the number of rows, shape[1] gives you the number of columns.

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]])
a.shape
>> [2,4]
a.shape[0]
>> 2
a.shape[1]
>> 4
```

However, if my array only have one row, then it returns [No.of columns, ]. And shape[1] will be out of the index. For example

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
a.shape
>> [4,]
a.shape[0]
>> 4    //this is the number of column
a.shape[1]
>> Error out of index
```

Now how do I get the number of rows of an numpy array if the array may have only one row?

Thank you

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The concept of *rows* and *columns* applies when you have a 2D array. However, the array `numpy.array([1,2,3,4])` is a 1D array and so has only one dimension, therefore `shape` rightly returns a single valued iterable.

For a 2D version of the same array, consider the following instead:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4]]) # notice the extra square braces
>>> a.shape
(1, 4)
```

Comment: @YichuanWang And if you start with a 1-d array (`a_1d = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])`), you can always transform it into a 2-d array with eg `a_2d = a_1d[None, :]`

Answer (score 4):

Rather then converting this to a 2d array, which may not be an option every time - one could either check the `len()` of the tuple returned by shape or just check for an index error as such:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
print(a.shape)
# (4,)
print(a.shape[0])
try:
    print(a.shape[1])
except IndexError:
    print("only 1 column")
```

Or you could just try and assign this to a variable for later use (or return or what have you) if you know you will only have 1 or 2 dimension shapes:

```
try:
    shape = (a.shape[0], a.shape[1])
except IndexError:
    shape = (1, a.shape[0])

print(shape)
```